# Entity Framework работа с тяжелыми таблицами

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня есть таблица городов около 2.5 миллионов записей (весит 2гб) и если в SQL запрос выполняется моментально по поиску, то Entity Framework начинает сначала всю таблицу выгружать в память и все подвисает на достаточно долгое время, не подскажите как работать с такими тяжелыми таблицами.

```
        var country = _repo.Get<Country>(x => x.CountryId == 1);
        var cities = country.Cities.Where(x => 
        x.TitleRu.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("ново")).ToList();
```

Я проверил запрос в `LINQPad 5` там аналогичный запрос выполняется тоже моментально

Comment: Пишите правильные запросы :) Покажите запрос, который тормозит

Comment: создайте индексы

Comment: @АндрейNOP, У меня таблица городов связана с таблицей стран по по `foreignkey`. И я пишут запрос через объект страны `var cities = country.Cities.ToList()` типо все города страны, но он начинает выгружать всю таблицу.

Comment: @Yaroslav я выставлял индексы, при создании таблиц

Comment: @Идентикон, предоставьте больше кода, то так ничего не понятно

Comment: Ну так не пишите `ToList()`, если вам не нужны все записи, именно эта операция все их материализует

Comment: @Идентикон foreign key != индекс

Comment: @4per, при создание в code first , он сам добавляет таким полям индекс

Comment: @АндрейNOP, так, если я не использую `ToList()`, просто отложу выполнения запроса. А когда мне понадобится он также повиснет.

Comment: Покажите код запроса с EF. Мы вам укажем, где ошибка. А так обсуждать нечего.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Добавил пример

Comment: Какой тип у country.Cities? IEnumerable<City>?

Comment: @PashaPash List

Comment: List - не IQueryable. Он не умеет отображать запросы в базу.

Comment: @PashaPash у меня установлен `virtual` для этого листа и он ентити фреймворк должен в него записывать значение по вторичному ключу. А разве можно делать ссылки по вторичному ключу через IQueryable?

Comment: @Идентикон а все равно, virtual или нет - на выходе вы получаете объект List<T> со всем внутри

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, проблема в том, что ваш Cities - это `List<City>`. List - не `IQueryable`. Любая работа со списком вытянет в память весь список, и потом уже отфильтрует его.

Если хотите работать с Cities через EF, с отображением запроса в базу - или выбирайте из контекста изначально Cities, с фильтром по City.CountryID

```
var cities = _repo.Get<City>(x => x.City.Country.CountryId == 1 && 
                                  x.TitleRu.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("ново"))
).ToList();
```

или работайте через [`context.Entry(...).Collection(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли, еще посмотрел в интерфейсе репозитория, как раз тоже стояли IEnumerable и получалось так, как вы сказали выдергивает весь список и потом фильтрует.